# Trick for dealing with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

When finding the constrained maximum or minimum, the equation used is 
$$\nabla f =\lambda \nabla g$$ where $\nabla f$ is the objective function and $\nabla g$ is the constraint function.

However, this method might fail if $\nabla g = 0$ at the extremas.

So is this equation correct to use in such situations?
$$\lambda  \nabla f =\nabla g$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do, you have to check two cases. The standard thing is to find points $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ and either

- $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$, or
- $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \lambda \nabla g(\mathbf x)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

(Your constraint might also look like $g(\mathbf x)= c$, but we can put it into the standard form above by writing it as $g(\mathbf x) - c = 0$. So I'll assume $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ is the constraint.)

You're right that you could take the first possibility into account by moving the $\lambda$ to the other side, but then another case "falls out": you now need to find points $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ where $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ and either

- $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \lambda \nabla f(\mathbf x)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, or
- $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$.

Either formulation is equivalent for actually finding the set of potential optima (and in the end, they find the same set of points).

We could even imagine a third formulation: finding points $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ where $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ and either

- $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \lambda \nabla f(\mathbf x)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, or
- $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = \lambda \nabla g(\mathbf x)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

This would also be valid, though redundant: the only cases found by one equation but not the other are cases where $\lambda =0$, so solving either of the formulations above would be simpler.

---

That being said, the first formulation is the better way to think about it. Essentially, the existence of *any* values $\mathbf x$ such that $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ and $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$ means that $g$ is somehow an ill-behaved constraint at $\mathbf x$. (For example, this sort of thing happens when the set $\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : g(\mathbf x) = 0\}$ has isolated points.) This can also happen if we introduce unnecessary complexity into the constraint: for example, turn the constraint $x+y-1=0$ into the constraint $(x+y-1)^2=0$ and now every point where $g(x,y)=0$ also satisfies $\nabla g(x,y) = (0,0)$.

In other words, the first formulation says "either the constraint is degenerate, or the gradient equation holds", which gives a useful interpretation to the "awkward" alternative.

In much greater generality, if we allowed multiple constraints and/or allowed some constraints to be inequalities, the condition of having no point $\mathbf x$ where $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$ and $g(\mathbf x) = 0$ would generalize to one of the regularity conditions of the [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: Why g(x) has to be 0?

Comment: Well, you're using Lagrange multipliers to solve the optimization problem "maximize $f(\mathbf x)$ such that $g(\mathbf x) = 0$", right?

Comment: True, but why can't g(x) be equal to a number c? I mean yeah I get in my case g(x) really is 0, but is it possible to such type of problem to occur in g(x)=c?

Comment: I'm used to the convention where we write the constraint in the standard form $g(\mathbf x)=0$; if you have $g(\mathbf x) = c$, you can rewrite that as $h(\mathbf x) = 0$ for $h(\mathbf x) = g(\mathbf x) - c$. I'll edit the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Okay, one last thing, is using these two equations a valid way of calculating ALL extremas? $$\nabla f =\lambda \nabla g~ ;~\lambda \nabla f = \nabla g$$

Comment: It's valid (assuming you mean that one OR the other must hold), but it's also more complicated than it needs to be. Once you use $\lambda$ in one equation, you can assume $\lambda=0$ in the other equation, since that's the only case that remains not dealt with.

Comment: Unrelated, but can you also tell me what does # means? Source https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x+in+y%5E2%2Bx%5E4-x%5E3%3D0

Comment: `Root[#1^4-#1^3+y^2&,1]` stands for "the first root of the polynomial $f(x) = x^4-x^3+y^2$" in Mathematica syntax.

Comment: Okay thank you very much